# Dynamically add/remove fields to a form in Rails3 using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Does anyone know an simple/easy way or the best way to add fields dynamically in a form, using JQuery in rails3?

Comment: have a look here http://www.pradipchitrakar.com.np/blog/dynamically-add-remove-textfield.html maybe it's what you looking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless what server-side language you're using, you can just create elements with the jQuery constructor and append it to a form node. For instance:

```
$('<input>', {
    id:   'my_new_input_id',
}).appendTo($('#my_form_id'));
```

would create a new `input` control and append it to a form with the id `my_form_id`.

**edit**

relating to your comment: To remove a dynamically created element, a good approach is to store a reference in a variable. Doing that you can call `.remove()` or `.detach()` later:

```
var my_new_input_element = $('<input>', {
    id:   'my_new_input_id',
}).appendTo($('#my_form_id'));

// ... lots of code

my_new_input_element.remove();
```

ref.: [.appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/), [.remove()](http://.remove), [.detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)

Comment: Thanks jAndy, that worked for adding - any idea how to remove fields?